# Entity Framework many-to-many With additional column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, tph

I have two classes:

```
public class Address
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ToAddressMessageLink> MessagesTo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CopyAddressMessageLink> MessagesCopyTo { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ToAddressMessageLink> To { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CopyAddressMessageLink> CopyTo { get; set; }
}
```

And I need to save connection between them in a **single** table.
If I simply put many-to-many relation between, EF wouldn't realize what type of connection is actually set(table rows will be identical for them). 
So I have to create a link class with a discriminator like following:

```
public class AddressMessageLink
{
    public int LinkType { get; set; }
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
    public Guid MessageId { get; set; }
}
```

But it also doesn't work because I can't set link type/ 
So I have to use TPH here:

```
public abstract class AddressMessageLink
{
    public int LinkType { get; set; }
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
    public Guid MessageId { get; set; }
}

public class CopyAddressMessageLink : AddressMessageLink
{
    public virtual AddressDto Address { get; set; }
    public virtual MessageDto Message { get; set; }
}

public class ToAddressMessageLink : AddressMessageLink
{
    public virtual AddressDto Address { get; set; }
    public virtual MessageDto Message { get; set; }
}
```

With a composite key:

```
HasKey(x=>new {x.AddressId, x.MessageId, x.LinkType});
```

But it doesn't work either, because EF:

> "The foreign key component AddressId is not a declared property on type ToAddressMessageLink".

If I put `AddressId` and `MessageId` into derived class I can't set key because there is no component of it in base class.

What can I do it this situation?

Answer (score 1):

If u have to classes, that you want to connect, you need to create a class that will connect yours two tables. And you did that there:

```
public class AddressMessageLink
{
    public int LinkType { get; set; }
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
    public Guid MessageId { get; set; }
}
```

But you don't join virtual attributes. So you have to do like this.

In your tables definition:

```
public class Address
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AddressMessageLink> AddressMessageLink { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AddressMessageLink> AddressMessageLink { get; set; }
}
```

And in `AddressMessageLink` object:

```
public class AddressMessageLink
{
    public int LinkType { get; set; }
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
    public Guid MessageId { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual Message Message { get; set; }
}
```

That will connect your tables as many to many.

Comment: it would work in thas case, but if i add another property of type ICollection<AddressMessageLink>, it would lead to "The relationship Address_MessagesTo' was not loaded because the type is not available"

Comment: Show me, what you want to do, what another property of this type ? 

You can define only one property of this type in one object.

Comment: `(public class Address
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AddressMessageLink> MessageTo { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<AddressMessageLink> MessageCopyTo { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AddressMessageLink> Address { get; set; }public virtual ICollection<AddressMessageLink> CopyToAddress { get; set; }
})`